# Problems with running Wald Test in Julia

Tags: statistics, julia

i´ve a problem with running the following function to perform a Wald Test on my Data. It always displays me the error message that the variable theta is not defined. I tried to define it in struct WaldTestFun{F, T, Z} but this does not work. The error message im getting is
Error Message = UndefVarError: theta not defined
Here is a part of the code:

```
 using LinearAlgebra
 using Optim
 using PrettyTables
 using Printf
 using Statistics
 using StatsBase
 using StatsFuns


 struct WaldTest
 tbl::NamedTuple
 rankmin::Int64
 rankₘₐₓ::Int64
 end

 struct WaldTestFun{F, T, Z}
 f::F
 r::Int64
 vecsigma::T
 Vhat::Z
 end

 (wf::WaldTestFun)(theta) = wf.f(theta, wf.r, wf.vecsigma, wf.Vhat) #Here the error occurs

 function waldobjfun(th, r, vecsigma, Vhat)
 r,k = size(theta)                                                 #Here the error occurs
 theta = reshape(theta, r+1, length(th)÷(r+1))
 sigmamat = diagm(0=>theta[1,:].^2) .+ theta[2:r+1,:]'*theta[2:r+1,:]
 tempsigma = sigmamat[findall(tril(ones(size(sigmamat))).==1)]
 (vecsigma -tempsigma)' /Vhat *(vecsigma - tempsigma)
 end

 X = randn(100,10);
 fm = Factotum.FactorModel(X, 3)

 function waldtest(fm::FactorModel, minrank::Int = 0, maxrank::Int = 2)
 X = copy(fm.X)
 T, n = size(X)
 ## Normalize factor
 Xs = X / diagm(0=>sqrt.(diag(cov(X))))
 covX = cov(Xs)
 meanX = mean(Xs, dims=1)
 vecsigma = vech(covX)
 bigN = length(vecsigma)
 Vhat = Array{Float64}(undef, bigN, bigN)
 varvecsig = zeros(n,n,n,n);
```

Comment: `theta` is not a parameter of `waldjobfun`, only `th` is.